# Combine list elements of lists with same structure

Tags: r, list, merge, tidyverse

I have a list with inner lists that all have the same structure, in my case, they are character vectors. Now I want to have a list that combines these inner lists by a function (in this case simply `c`). A minimal example:

```
list(
  list(one = "a", 
       two = "b", 
       three = "c"), 
  list(one = "d", 
       two = c("e", "f"), 
       three = "g")
  )
```

My desired output:

```
list(
  one = c("a", "d"),
  two = c("b", "e", "f"),
  three = c("c", "g")
)
```

I have searched quite long and there were similar questions but I haven't found exactly what I need. I also think that the answers to similar questions were quite complicated. Don't get me wrong, of course, it's no big deal to solve this problem, but I cannot imagine that there is no really elegant way/a one liner for this. Preferably with `tidyverse` syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another approach using first `transpose` and then `unlist` wrapped arround `map`:

```
library(purrr)

map(transpose(l), unlist)
```

output:

```
$one
[1] "a" "d"

$two
[1] "b" "e" "f"

$three
[1] "c" "g"
```

Comment: Great, great, great! My favorite, so far! :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

Unlist 1 level, stack and unstack:

```
unstack(stack(unlist(l, recursive = FALSE)))
# $one
# [1] "a" "d"
# 
# $two
# [1] "b" "e" "f"
# 
# $three
# [1] "c" "g"
```

Comment: `unstack(stack(unlist(l, FALSE)))`

Comment: This method passes all test cases!! +1. Also no need of spliting, just unstack the df

Comment: @onyambu thanks edited, somehow I always forget about existance of unstack...

Answer (score 3):

In base R, you can use `do.call` with `Map`. In a list, `do.call` is particularly useful to apply a function to each of its element by index (check e.g. `do.call(\(x, y) x + y, list(c(7, 9, 2), c(6, 2, 8)))`). Here, since it is a list of lists, one has to use an `apply*` function on top (like `Map`, which takes two arguments) to `c`oncatenate. This required the list to be symmetric:

```r
l <- list(
  list(one = "a", 
       two = "b", 
       three = "c"), 
  list(one = "d", 
       two = c("e", "f"), 
       three = "g")
)

do.call(Map, c(c, l))

# $one
# [1] "a" "d"
# 
# $two
# [1] "b" "e" "f"
# 
# $three
# [1] "c" "g"
```

In `tidyverse` language, this can be done with `exec`:

```r
library(purrr)
exec(Map, !!!c(c, l))
```

Comment: Nice, thank you very much! Could you explain it a bit, please?

Comment: This is a great answer, unfortunately it would fail when the list is not symetric across all elements. ie suppose there was no `two` in the 2nd list, then the method fails. I would rather propose to use `map(transpose(l), unlist)`